# Mysql SUM amount Between Month And Year

Tags: php, mysql

I need report of products amount, between month and years...
am use this query but fetch amount is `0`

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as amt 
FROM `products` 
WHERE `cid`='14' 
AND `sid`='24' 
AND MONTH(`date`)='03' 
AND YEAR(`date` BETWEEN '2014' AND '2016')
```

Comment: did u means show database structure?

Comment: like enter 3 records the month 03 and year is 2014, the record cid = 14 and sid = 24,

Comment: @fana plz share your table structure and some dummy data

Comment: Table structure is.... 
`id    cid    sid    amount    date
1     14     24      200      2014-03-09
2     14     24      30       2014-03-09
3     14     24      50       2015-05-08`

this is my Data base structure..

Comment: if your DATE field's type is DATETIME, follow Waldson Patricio's answer.

Comment: @Bit_hunter date field type is DATE

Comment: follow Waldson Patricio's answer

Comment: am follow his answer but cant get correct result. when i run his query, this query print amount with every next year.. Like 03-2014 have record is database and 03-2015 no record, @Waldson SQL query print amount 2014 and also 2015.. this is not correct answer

Comment: try it SELECT SUM(amount) as amt 
FROM `products` 
WHERE `cid`='14' 
AND `sid`='24' 
AND MONTH(`date`)='3' 
AND YEAR(`date`) BETWEEN '2014' AND '2016'

Comment: @Bit_hunter I try your query, but return amt is null..

Comment: see  my answer below

Answer (score 2):

Try this:  (will bring data from 03/2014, 03/2015, 03/2016)

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as amt 
FROM `products` 
WHERE `cid`='14' 
AND `sid`='24' 
AND MONTH(`date`)='03' 
AND YEAR(`date`) BETWEEN '2014' AND '2016'
```

If you want to bring all data between these two dates, try this:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as amt 
FROM `products` 
WHERE `cid`='14' 
AND `sid`='24' 
AND `date` >= '2014-03-01 00:00:00' AND  `date` < '2016-04-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: @Bit_hunter This answer not work for me. I did not accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query:-[Tested myself]

Table Data-

```
id cid sid amount date 
1 14 24 200 2014-03-09 
2 14 24 30 2014-03-09 
3 14 24 50 2015-05-08
```

Query:-

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as amt FROM products WHERE cid='14' AND sid='24' AND MONTH(date)='3' AND YEAR(date) BETWEEN '2014' AND '2016'
```

Output:-

```
amt
230
```

[image]

***Note:- Make sure your Date column's datatype is DATE***

Comment: `Please check screen shot repeat amount September, 2013 and same amount repeat on September, 2014, this record fetching via your query.enter code here`

Check this Link i upload screen shot... [link](http://prntscr.com/5rp65w)

Comment: See table data http://prntscr.com/5rphoo and query result http://prntscr.com/5rphfj

Comment: when use loop upper this query and repeat year and month multi time this query again print record to next year with same month, you see last share screen shot. hope so u understand me. When i Submit form with two dates, I also want months list on left column between two dates. for month list I use `foreach` after this loop i run your query, when query run in loop he repeat record between year and same month... See My screen shot again [link](http://prntscr.com/5rpoxp)

Comment: @fana would you please try with some dummy data and share your query result here. As this query is working fine on my dummy table.

Comment: am share you my database table and data, also accepting result sheet, I want monthly report, First table is Categories, Second is Sections, And Last is products, when Choose any one category, search record from table products, there have `cid` and `sid` than fetch record by month and year, share you screen shot hope so you understand [screen_shot](http://prntscr.com/5saa1d)

Comment: @Fana There is no need to use CID in products table. BTW in above mentioned data, of which months records you want?

Comment: like i search FOODS & VAGITABLE between 2014-10-01 to 2015-02-01.. query return between months record with `sum` amount. like share my report under tables in screen shots..

Comment: try this query  
`select food.foods,vegetables.vegetables ,food.month from (SELECT sum(amount) as foods,DATE_FORMAT(date,'%M %y') as month FROM `products`,`sections` WHERE (date between '2014-10-01' and '2015-02-01') and sections.id=products.sid and sections.id=14 group by month(date) ) food,
 SELECT sum(amount) as vegetables,DATE_FORMAT(date,'%M %y') as month FROM `products`,`sections` WHERE (date between '2014-10-01' and '2015-02-01') and sections.id=products.sid and sections.id=15 group by month(date)) vegetables
where food.month=vegetables.month`

Comment: I run your query but return Null Record.. share with screen shot please check it.... (http://prntscr.com/5sftqn)

Comment: my table data http://prntscr.com/5sqopd and query result http://prntscr.com/5sqowv